# Angular 2 Webpack demo not working

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I have completed steps for [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#configure-webpack) and I got error:

```
Failed to load app.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load app.component.html undefined
```

My [Github Repo](https://github.com/TeodorKolev/Angular2-starter)

I have spotted another web page on web with same problem:
[Example](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/)

Could problem be in Angular itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the issue by starting to "debug" angular2-template-loader with console log adding:
console.log("+++++++"+source); just after the function definition.
By doing it I saw that not all the ts file were processed and in particular app.component.ts.

Then I saw in the src folder .js and .map files, so I deleted it and added in the tsconfig.json those properties after compilerOptions (outside it):
"compileOnSave": false,
"buildOnSave": false

Run again npm start and now the application loads successfully.

@TeodorKolev: I cloned your repo, npm install and npm start and replicated the error.
I deleted the .js and .map files created, then added the properties and then npm start again and now it's working.

Comment: can you do a pull request?

Comment: I'll do it after launch :) just a curiosity, do you use webstorm as editor? if I just delete .js and .map and I run npm start without open the editor it works. The problem is with the editor open because it compile ts in js and create the sourcemaps.

Comment: Pull Request sent!

Comment: wait, it starts to generate those files again. Anyway the problem are those generated files from the editor. Now I just disabled Typescript compiler from WebStorm. In any case delete .js and .map from the repository :)